# Running on cloud servers

Tags: python, server, cloud

I have written a python program with "csv" file as backend. Actually the algorithm which is involved performs long and deep numerical computations.So I am not able to run it on my local computer.Last time,when I ran it,it took more than 2 hrs but didn't fully execute.Can anyone tell me Is there any way of executing the program with csv file as backend on some servers?
Or is there any other way to do it?
Also,I don't want to use spark for the purpose.

Comment: Why does the program terminate after 2 hours? You have probably some serious errors. You should first get your program running correct locally.

Comment: No,actually its a big algorithm so it takes exponential time as we increase one of the parameters of the algorithm.So for small parameters,it is running around 20 min but for large values of the parameters,It may take many hours.